# Subject of an email

Tags: email, letter-writing

So my native language is Spanish and I'm about to write an email to a colleague in English asking about several stuff. While doing so I started wondering about the subject of the email I was writing and got curious about the subject I wanted to put at first. In Spanish I could just put the exact equivalent of "consultation" and that works fine... in Spanish, but in English just doesn't seems to be right to me, or is it ok?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean the subject line of the email? What is the email about? Does "consultation" refer to the fact that you are asking questions in the email?

Comment: Yes. The email involves several questions about the possibility to apply for a Ph.D.... and Yes

Comment: P.S. _Several_ is always plural; it can't modify a singular mass noun like _stuff_. _A few things_ is the idiom.

Comment: We can't tell you how to phrase your subject line. But if you want to know of a word that's *better* than *consultation*, you have to tell us why you think *consultation* doesn't work—and what other words you've considered and rejected.

Comment: hmmm... It just doesn't sounds right to me, but that could be just a matter of perspective since my mother laguage is Spanish not English, and honestly I have no idea which one is the appropriate in this context, I considered "questions", "consult", "doubt", that's all I got

Answer (score 1):

"Enquiry" might be a more suitable word than consultation, as "consultation" generally refers to a meeting in person, rather than an email. For example, your subject could be

> "Enquiry about PhD opportunity"

Another option would simply be "questions". For example:

> "A few questions about  ..X.. Phd opportunity"